Can converge almost sure pass through nice function?
Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a continuous function, and $c$ is a given finite constant. Fixing $x$, $f(x,y)$ is strictly increasing with respect to $y$, and there exists a unique $y_x$ such that $f(x,y_x)=c$.
Now consider a series of random variables $\{X_n\}$, and assume that $X_n\to x^*$ a.s., where $x^*$ is a constant. With each $X_n$, we can have a random variable $Y_n$ such that $f(X_n,Y_n)=c$.
Since the properties of $f$ look very good to me, I wonder if it is true that $Y_n\to Y$ a.s.?
I deeply appreciate any guidance!

I will prove $y_x$ is continuous, from which your conjecture immediately follows.
Consider the set of points where $f(x, y) \le c$. Pick some $x_0$. $f$ is continuous, so $S$ is closed. $S$ contains all its accumulation points, so in particular it contains $(x_0, \limsup_{x \to x_0}f(x))$. So
$$f(x_0, \limsup_{x \to x_0}y_x(x)) \le c$$
Similarly, we have
$$f(x_0, \liminf_{x \to x_0}y_x(x)) \ge c$$
But
$$\limsup_{x \to x_0}y_x(x) \ge \liminf_{x \to x_0}y_x(x)$$
and $f$ is increasing in $y$, so
$$f(x_0, \limsup_{x \to x_0}y_x(x)) \ge f(x_0, \liminf_{x \to x_0}y_x(x))$$
Which taken together means
$$f(x_0, \limsup_{x \to x_0}y_x(x)) = f(x_0, \liminf_{x \to x_0}y_x(x)) = c$$
So since $y_x$ is strictly increasing:
$$\limsup_{x \to x_0}y_x(x)) = \liminf_{x \to x_0}y_x(x) = y_x(x_0)$$
In other words
$$\lim_{x \to x_0}y_x(x) = y_x(x_0)$$
So $y_x$ is continuous, which means $X_n \to x^*$ implies $y_x(X_n) \to y_x(x^*)$ So if the probability of the former is $1$, the probability of the latter is also $1$.

Many thanks for your answer! But I don't understand why $(x_0, y_{x})$ can be in the set $S$? If $x_0$ goes to $x$ in an arbitrary way, how do you ensure that $f(x_0,y_x)\leq c$?

The defining property of $y_x$ is that $f(x, y_x(x)) = c$ so every $x$ is the limit gives $c$, so $x$ is in $S$. And $S$ is closed so the limit is also in $S$.

Got it, thanks!
